# Assessing residuals from a regression model

Tags: regression, residuals, goodness-of-fit, model

I am trying to understand what the residuals from a regression convey about the model's adequacy/ability to explain the variance in the data.
I read that if we are able to take the residuals from a regression model (say Model 1) and build another model (Model 2), by regressing a new set of predictors on it , then unless the R-square of Model 2 is zero, we conclude that Model 1 does not explain the variation in the original data adequately.

Could someone explain the concept of building a new model M2 with the residuals from a previous model as the response variable?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you described "the *concept* of building a new model with the residuals from a previous model as the response variable" quite well. What is it you are seeking?

Comment: I just wanted to know the rationale behind the concept--- why would we expect model 2 to have R-square = 0 ? I think the reply below is what I was looking for. Additionally, is this method often used to check model adequacy? Is it a reliable or recommended method? I have usually only read about plotting residuals and looking at Chi-square or F -tests for model goodness of fit. This was a new one.

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. Some of that would be good to edit into your question.

Answer (score 1):

If explanatory variables from model one  almost perfectly explained your response variable,  you would be left only with residuals that are called white noise. And noise is noise. Nothing can explain it.  It is mix of measurement errors and so on. So,  if you regress whatever explanatory variables on that noise in the model2 you should get nothing out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Additionally, is this method often used to check model adequacy? Is it a reliable or recommended method? I have usually only read about plotting residuals and looking at Chi-square or F -tests for model goodness of fit.

Comment: In my experience, after fitting a model,  diagnostic tests are made for autocorrelation,  heteroscedasticity and so on... these tests are usually done on residuals. They test for certain pattern in residuals. And they are usually regression based.  So... if your model 1 is adequate,  they should not show anything. Otherwise,  your model 1 might not be ok.

Comment: This is wrong. Maybe I don't get the question, but noise is not noise. Everything is about conditional probabilities. What's noise to a set of predictors is not necessarily noise to another set of predictors. Therefore building a model M2 with a different set of predictors say not much about the model M1. If M2 is explaining the residuals of M1, it means you can combine M1 and M2 to have a better model.

Comment: I did not want to complicate things... by adding variables,  one can of course always improve the fit.